# How to print http response body in Go?

Tags: go

I'm using Google Cloud Run to run the application (e.g. [sample application](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#writing)) I have the following script in Go:

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "os"
        "os/exec"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Print("helloworld: received a request")

        cmd := exec.CommandContext(r.Context(), "/bin/sh", "script.sh")
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
        out, err := cmd.Output()
        if err != nil {
                w.WriteHeader(500)
        }
        w.Write(out)
}

func main() {
        log.Print("helloworld: starting server...")

        http.HandleFunc("/", handler)

        port := os.Getenv("PORT")
        if port == "" {
                port = "8080"
        }

        log.Printf("helloworld: listening on %s", port)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), nil))
}
```

I need to log.print responses body from script.sh commands. How can I do it?

Comment: https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/wOYk/advanced-command-execution-in-go-with-osexec.html

Comment: Your question seems to answer itself, you `log.Print` by calling `log.Print`, which you've already used elsewhere in your code, so it's unclear what you're having trouble with. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: No relation with Cloud Run, it's pure Go question. You have lot of tutorial/example of this on the Internet. However, why to call a SH script in Go code? Why to not code all in Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server

> w.Write(out)

sends response from script.sh as []byte. You can add above that line the following
log.Print(string(out))